# Android - Increase Area of Drop Zone

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, dropshadow

I am following http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html and what I currently struggling with is, that I want to drag a relatively big view on a smaller button.

It seems `ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED` is only fired, if the touchpoint (center of the drag shadow) is within the bounds of the target view. However, I would like it to accept drops when the bounds of the shadow and the dropzone overlap. Is this possible?

(Note: I know, I could define a separate view as the drop zone and make it bigger than the actual drop-zone button, but that really complicates my layout, and I would rather work with the current view).